# Get count of users till a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by

I am having below two tables used in the join

**TABLE1 :** rat_proj_duration_map
**Columns:** UID,Hour_val,month_val

**TABLE2 :** users
**Columns:** UID, status, left_on

Here Status will contain texts('Act','InAct')

Now, I am trying to get count of UIDs grouped by month_val field as like below

```
select count(r.uid) as cnt, r.month_val
from rat_proj_duration_map r
    inner join users u on r.uid = u.uid 
where  r.year_val = 2018 
group by r.month_val
order by month_val
```

The above Query gives count of the records in month wise.

But, I am trying to ignore the 'Inactivated' users (Status field in users table) from the date(left_on from users table) of left.

So if the user was left on '2018-03-27', then that user record should be counted upto march month, not after that.

What's the condition to be added to my Query

**Example Output:**
If there are 100 users records and one user left_on '2018-03-27' with status 'Inactivated' then my result should look like below

```
Count  Month_val
100      1
100      2
100      3
99       4
99       5
99       6
99       7
99       8
99       9
99       10
99       11
99       12
```

Comment: Is your table `rat_proj_duration_map` some kind of calendar table? We can't run that query you provided, nor have access to your objects. All I can tell you with the information we have is add a further clause to your `WHERE`. *Maybe* `AND DATEPART(MONTH,u.dateleft) <= r.month_val` (No idea what field has the date left in it)? That clause won't be SARGable though.

Comment: `rat_proj_duration_map` contains the month_val as integer

Comment: Yes, i know that, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use `r.month_val`. Your comment doesn't tell me anything additional about the table though, I'm afraid.

Comment: Left_on will be filled by a datetimestamp when a user is 'Inactivated', So I have to ignore the users data from the month value of the exit date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the users by each project depending on their disable date. You can do this with an additional joining clause (or in the `WHERE` in this case).

```
DECLARE @FilterYear INT = 2018

select 
    count(r.uid) as cnt, 
    r.month_val
from 
    rat_proj_duration_map r
    inner join users u on r.uid = u.uid 
where  
    r.year_val = @FilterYear AND
    (
        u.left_on IS NULL OR
        YEAR(u.left_on) > @FilterYear OR
        (YEAR(u.left_on) = @FilterYear AND R.month_val <= MONTH(u.left_on))
    )
group by 
    r.month_val
order by 
    month_val
```

Keep in mind that we are comparing year and months (without days). You will have to consider what happens when the user is deactivated in the middle of the month.

Comment: Thanks, but your SQL always gives only three rows (Jan,Feb,Mar)

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi edited, added check of left_on null value. Run it again please.

Comment: Thanks a lot, You are rocking; Yes I need it for month basis not date basis, so if the user left on any dates no issues

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN u.status = 'InAct' AND u.left_on < DATEADD(month, month_val - 1, DATEADD(year, year_val - 1900, 0)) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS cnt, r.month_val
FROM rat_proj_duration_map r
INNER JOIN users u ON r.uid = u.uid
WHERE r.year_val = 2018
GROUP BY r.year_val, r.month_val
ORDER BY r.year_val, r.month_val
```

The expression `DATEADD(month, month_val - 1, DATEADD(year, year_val - 1900, 0))` will convert `2018, 3` to `2018-03-01`. You need to NOT count those records where user status is a inactive and user left earlier than year-month-01.

[SQL Fiddle with dummy data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f423b/3)

Comment: Your Query doesn't select the count of UID, I think

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi fixed.

Comment: How Can I get the distinct UID from your query

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi change `COUNT(CASE... THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE... THEN NULL ELSE r.uid END)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try this query (necessary comments in code):

```
select [count] - [left_count] from 
(
    select [left_month_val],
           --this will give amount of users left UP TO particular month
           SUM([left_count]) over (order by [left_month_val] rows between unbounded preceding and current row) [left_count]
    from (
        --here you count how many users left in particular months
        select DATEPART(month, [left_on]) [left_month_val], COUNT(*) [left_count]
        from [users]
        group by DATEPART(month, [left_on])
    ) [a]
) [u] join (
    --here you count how many users were there in particular months
    select [month_val], count(*) [count]
    from rat_proj_duration_map
    group by [month_val]
) [r] on [u].[left_month_val] = [r].[month_val]
```

Also, keep in mind that none of the query includes year, so you should add another grouping variable. Unfortunately, I couldn't try this myself, as you didn't give example data.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
select count(case when u.status='Act' then r.uid end) as cnt, r.month_val
from rat_proj_duration_map r
inner join users u on r.uid = u.uid 
where  r.year_val = 2018 
group by r.month_val
order by month_val
```

Comment: That won't work. Once an user is not marked as `'Act'` they will be discounted from all months, not just the subsequent ones.